# Spring AspectJ Style AOP

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

I have a Java app that uses Spring, and I have the aspect

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect
{

    @Pointcut("execution (* com.mycompany.MyClass.*(..))")
    public void doStuff() {}

    @Around("doStuff()")
    public Object aroundDoStuff(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable
    {
        System.out.println("before doStuff);
      try
      {
        return pjp.proceed();
      }
      finally
      {
        System.out.println("after doStuff");
      }
  }
}
```

Then my spring bean file has

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />
<bean id="MyAspect"
    class="com.mycompany.MyAspect" />
```

Now I would expect that all methods in MyClass get matched by the pointcut above, but that doesn't seem to be the case (only one of the methods seems to have the advice applied). I'm not sure if this has to do with the fact that I'm proxying a class or not, but does anyone see what I might be doing wrong here?

**EDIT**: The code is called from a main class that does something like this:

```
ApplicationContext cxt; // lookup the cxt
MyClass mc = (MyClass) cxt.getBean("MyClassBean");
mc.doSomething(); // I expect the advice to be applied here.
```

thanks,
Jeff

Comment: Could you show us the MainClass? Does it call methods internally (I mean, a method of MainClass calls another method of the same instance)?

Comment: I've added a relevant snippet from main.

Comment: Is `doSomething()` public non-final?

Comment: Yep. Though in my actual production code, doSomething does override a method in the super class that is protected (but my class makes it public).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out the issue is because I was proxying a class and not an interface. I needed to change the pointcut to match all of the classes that implemented the interface and then used the `target` pointcut to filter down to MyClass.

Edit: Adding details...

If MyClass extends AbstractMyClass and implements MyInterface, I wanted all methods in MyInterface to be advised, but this was not the case. I incorrectly declared my pointcut as:

```
@Pointcut(execution(* com.mycompany.MyClass.methodInAbstract()))
```

Changing it to

```
@Pointcut(execution(* com.mycompany.MyInterface.methodInAbstract()) && target(com.mycompany.MyClass))
```

worked well.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have cglib in your CLASSPATH, this is because when you specify the proxy-target-class=true, a CGLIB based proxy is created, rather than the default java dynamic proxy based one. Can you try with CGLIB in the path or by removing the proxy-target-class attribute(assuming that your bean does have an interface which is needed for dynamic proxy to work).

EDIT 1: I tried your sample, and have put it in github at this location - git://github.com/bijukunjummen/mvc-samples.git, you can execute the test which exercises your scenario using - `mvn test -Dtest=TestSpringAOP` and it seems to work well. Can you please review this test and see how different it is from your case.

Comment: I do have CGLIB. The proxy is actually getting created, but the advice just doesn't seem to be executed (I printed out the class of the object when it was loaded and it was a CGLIB class).

Comment: @Jeff Did you get to try this sample that I had put in my Edit - git://github.com/bijukunjummen/mvc-samples.git

Comment: Biju, thanks for following up. It turned out the problem was that when my pointcut specified a target of a class type i.e. @Pointcut(execution(* com.mycompany.MyClass)) it did not advise methods that were in interfaces of MyClass if the method was implemented by a parent class of MyClass. I'll edit my answer to show the details.